# C# / Informix: Do I need to explicitly call Close on my DB Connection if it's in a using statement?

Tags: c#, database-connection, informix, using-statement

Basically, if I'm doing the following:

```
using (IfxConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetConnection())
{
    connection.Open();
    ...
    if (connection != null) connection.Close(); //Is this necessary?
}
```

Note: IfxConnection is an IBM class that inherits from DBConnection.

I know it won't hurt to leave it in there, but I'm at a point where I'm cleaning up and making my code as efficient as possible, so removing anything that's "extra" would be nice. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If IBM cleans up and calls `Close()` in its `IfxConnection` class on `Dispose()`, then it is safe to remove the last line.

According to the [docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.net_cc.doc/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2ConnectionClass.htm), yes, they do.

Basically, you'd have two choices:

- go with `using()` or
- forfeit `using()` and go for a `try{ ... } finally { if (connectionIsOpen) connection.Close()}`

*Using both of them is unnecessary.*

I would vote for using `using()`. (pun intended) ;-)

Just do not reuse - argh, again ;-) - the connection that is already disposed - but you wouldn't do that, anyway, do you? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Dispose` closes the connection for you.  Be careful though as it also clears the connection string.

Please see [`IfxConnection`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.net_cc.doc/dqx1db2connectionclass.htm) for these tips:

> - Calling Dispose on a IfxConnection object is different from calling Close. For example, Dispose clears the connection string while Close does not.
> - **[In reference to the `Close` method]** Closes the connection to the database. This is the preferred method of closing any open connection.